# Unity script is running on any button click

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, button

I have a button called ShareButton in the below screenshot that is linked to a script and it works fine but the same action of the script is executed every time I click on any other button.
The other buttons are not linked to the script but it keeps executing it while doing the right action of the button.

[image]

**EDIT :**

This is the other button that is just supposed to close the modal but is also running the script that has nothing to do with
it.
[image]

And this is the script of the 'ShareButton' :
[image]

Anyone knows why ? Thanks

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: No, `Update` is running permanently and as said `Input.GetMouseButtonDown` is handled globally regardless of where on the screen you click

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well, you do your thing on [`Input.GetMouseButtonDown`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetMouseButtonDown.html), completely regardless where on the screen this click happens!

[`Update`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Update.html) is called by Unity automatically **every frame**, not only by your button click.

Instead of calling `Update` on button click you rather want to have e.g. a

```
public void TakeScreenShot()
{
    StartCoroutine(TakeScreenshotAndShare());
}
```

and call this in your button.

Comment: Oh okay, I didn't know this specifity about Update, thank you !